# Adding fields to User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am managing to use `djangocontrib.auth.models.User`. I need to add phone number and profile pic field to the user model.

My serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField()
    profile_pic = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'], 
            phone_number=validated_data['phone_number'],
            profile_pic=validated_data['profile_pic'],
        )
        return user
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name','username', 'password',  'phone_number', 'profile_pic',)
```

But on creating user it returns `'phone_number' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`, I need help to create user with phone number and profile. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you extend the default User model?

Comment: I extend user by following this article. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html